# Spacy parser parses the whole document as one sentence

Tags: python, spacy

I'm building a Swedish model for Spacy on the suc3.0 trainingset. My problem is that the parser parses the whole document as one long sentence. I've been all over the documentation but can't find a solution. I've tried to disable the tagger when I parse, but that doesn't make a difference. From what I gather Spacy respects earlier sentence boundaries, so I thought it was that the swedish tag for sentence closing is MAD instead of the english '.', and that because of this the parser 'respected' that the whole doc was one long sentence, but like I said, disabling the tagger doesn't make any difference. The cetors I've initialized the model with is FastText. Would be really greatful for some help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide training docs that contain multiple sentences so that the parser sees sentence breaks while training. If the corpus doesn't contain paragraph information, you can just group together paragraph-sized groups of sentences (I normally use 10 sentences).

The tagger doesn't affect the parser at all and the individual tags / dependency labels shouldn't matter, either.

Comment: Ok, thankyou, but the wierd thing is that the parser marks punctuation as punct with the previous word as head, just like the english model does. And my training doc follows the simple training style which a parsed from a json file marked with paragraphs, sentences, id within the sentence etc.

Comment: I probably shouldn't use the simple training style when training the parser though, should I?

Comment: Now I used a universal dependencies training set (swedish lines) that I converted to json with paragraph info, id:s , trained with the cli train command and I still have the same problem. The training set only have one sentence per paragraph though, could that be the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the extraneous comments, followed your advice and it worked nice, thank you very much